# ASP.NET Membership Create User without requiresQuestionAndAnswer

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership

How can I use the CreateUser method in the Membership class without having to assign a question and answer?

I have disabled it in the web.config with the following setting.

```
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

I need the status output from the CreateUser method, but the overload requires a question and answer. Can anyone suggest how I can go about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but have you tried just passing null for those two parameters?

Answer (score 6):

you need to set parameters in web.config

```
<system.web>
<membership>
<providers>

<add name="YOURMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="con"  minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" applicationName="YourAppName" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647"/>
```

I tried this. Its working Fine. Thanks

Comment: Your answer's probably correct, but you should never set `passwordFormat="Clear"`. [Microsoft themselves note that this is insecure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat?view=netframework-4.8) -- it means you're storing your user's passwords in plaintext

Comment: @Lovethenakedgun ... Yes you are right.

*Clear - Not secure, do not use. Passwords are not encrypted.

*Encrypted - Not secure, do not use. Passwords are encrypted using the encryption settings determined by the machineKey element configuration.

*Hashed - Passwords are encrypted one-way using the SHA1 hashing algorithm. You can specify a hashing algorithm different than the SHA1 algorithm by using the hashAlgorithmType attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As another answerer mentioned, you just pass `null` in instead of `""`, or `string.Empty`.

When I first discovered this I though that the developers hadn't heard of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, and that we were venturing into WTF territory.

But of course, in their wisdom, they realised that `null` is conceptually different to an empty string, and in this case, when dealing with input from a user, we want to tell them their question is invalid if it's not specified.